# Blender not open in my laptop

Tags: opengl

Blender ver 3.6.2
After downloading and installing the software, it does not started because it show the popup window.
In this window it show the "the entry point not found ". Dll file like wsci not found.
Thanks you

Comment: Where did you find ver 3.6.2, or is that a typo? I don't see any ver 3.6.2 on the Blender.org website.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Could you please clarify the question? As it currently stands, it's unclear what exactly the problem is and which version we're actually talking about here. Thank you!